# JUnit 5 mock YearMonth.now but call real method for YearMonth.from

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5

My use-case is that I am using JUnit 5 and need to mock the static method `YearMonth.now()`.
In order to do so the solution I used was:

```
YearMonth defaultYearMonth = YearMonth.of(DEFAULT_YEAR, Month.MARCH);
try (MockedStatic<YearMonth> mockedScope = Mockito.mockStatic(YearMonth.class)) {
    mockedScope.when(YearMonth::now).thenReturn(defaultYearMonth);
    // Rest of the code
    // StepVerifier to verify a subscription
}
```

The problem now is that because of mocking the YearMonth in the mocked scope I cannot all the other methods are mocked. But I want to call the real method for `YearMonth.from()`.
To do so what I did was tried adding

```
mockedScope.when(() -> YearMonth.from(any())).thenCallRealMethod();
```

But this does not work and I am getting `null` where the `YearMonth.from(LocalDateTime)` is called.

I am not sure what I am missing. Is there a way to spy on a static method if maybe its due to mocking the `YearMonth` class? If not any help on how to achieve this with JUnit 5 will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Javadoc for `Mockito.mockStatic(Class<T>)` you'll see that all your static methods are mocked, which means you'll need to take care of them manually if they're used in the scope of your test.

> Creates a thread-local mock controller for ***all static methods*** of the given class or interface. [...]

The way to fix it is to use an extra parameter to your `mockStatic` method according to the Javadoc. The second parameters being **defaultAnswer**

> **defaultAnswer** – the default answer when invoking static methods.

```java
MockedStatic<YearMonth> mockedScope = Mockito.mockStatic(YearMonth.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)
```

Comment: Thanks for the above sol. Now I am not getting null but still not expected behavior

            YearMonth startMonth = YearMonth.from(transfersMetadata.getStartDate());
            YearMonth endMonth = YearMonth.from(transfersMetadata.getEndDate());
            return (int) ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(startMonth, endMonth) + 1;

I have the above code snippet. Its giving the difference of 1 month though I should be getting 12

Comment: What are your inputs inside of `transfersMetadata` @VarunSharma ?

Comment: @VarunSharma I've found it, look at the modified answer :)